# regex copy and paste

Tags: regex

Need some guidance on using regex to manipulate text.  I'm using textpad to do regex on some code.  I'd like to take a list of vars like this:

```
$var1;
$var2;
$var3;
```

and convert it into this:

```
$var1 = $this->var1;
$var2 = $this->var2;
$var3 = $this->var3;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Search: `^\$(\w+);$` Replace: `\$$1 = \$this->$1`. Or use `\1` instead of `$1` if `$1` is not working.

Comment: textpad editing php code

Comment: why did this question get marked to -3?

Comment: Because it's a poor question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified streeturtle's answer to handle an var names, find/replace

```
(\$.+)
```

by

```
$1 = \$object->$1
```

Answer (score 0):

In TextPad select find/replace and replace:

```
(\$var\d)
```

by

```
\1 = \$this->\1
```

Comment: I changed your replace code to this: $1 = \$this->$1and it also worked fine in textpad